# Content Wider Than Screen In Mobile- How to fix?

Tags: html, css, mobile, blogger

Content is wider than my screen in mobile, no idea how to resolve. This is the entire code for the mobile site.

[www.latoyah.co.uk](http://www.latoyah.co.uk) is my webpage, but only mobile affected.

Google has come back saying it is affecting usability.

The text just gets slightly cut off on the left-hand hand side. I would change the text size but apparently only that is already too small to read as well.

```
/*************************************************
*   Mobile Portrait                              *
*************************************************/

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .subscribe-box .block,.container {
        width:320px;
    }

.background-slider {
    height: 320px !important;
}
    #top-search{display:none}
#top-social {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999999999999;
    right: 0;
}


    #navigation-wrapper {
        display:none;
    }

    .slicknav_menu {
        display:block;
    }

    #logo img {
        max-width:320px;
        height:auto;
    }

    .post-header h1 a, .post-header h2 a, .post-header h1 {
        font-size:22px;
        letter-spacing:2px;
    }

    .post-image img {
        width:320px;
        height:auto;
    }

    .post-image.audio iframe {
        width:320px;
        height:auto;
    }

    .item-related {
        width:320px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }

    .share-box {
        width:36px; 
        height:36px; 
        line-height:36px;
        margin:0 4px;
    }

    .post-pagination .prev-post {
        width:320px;
    }
    .post-pagination .next-post {
        width:320px;
    }

    #respond textarea {
        width:90%;
    }

    .thecomment .author-img {
        display:none;
    }

    #widget-area .widget, #sidebar .widget {
        width:320px;
        margin-right:32px;
        float:left;
        margin-bottom:35px;
    }

    #footer-logo img {
        max-width:320px;
        height:auto;
    }

    #footer-social a i {
        height:28px;
        width:28px;
        line-height:28px;
        margin-right:0;
        font-size:12px;
    }
    #footer-social a {
        margin:0 5px;
    }
    #footer-social a span{
        display:none;
    }

    .wpcf7 textarea {
        width:75%;
    }

    .sp-grid li {
        width:320px;
    }
    .sp-grid li:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-right:0;
    }
    .sp-grid li:nth-child(2n+2) {
        margin-right:0;
    }

    .container.sp_sidebar #main {
        width:99%;
        margin-right:0;
    }
    .container.sp_sidebar #sidebar {
        width:100%;
    }

        .container.sp_sidebar #sidebar .widget {
            width:80%;
        }

#sidebar {

    float: left;

}


    .container.sp_sidebar .item-related {
        width:212px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }

.my-insta-box {
    display: none;
}


#footer-social a {

   border-left: none; 

    padding-left: 0px;
    }
.subscribe-box .form,.subscribe-box .caption {width: 100%;}
.caption img {width: 100%;}

.subscribe-box .form .email {width: 200px;}


.header-top #top-social, .header-top #top-search {
    position: static;
    margin: 0 0px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
article:nth-child(2n+2) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.post {

    width: 100%;

}

.header-top #top-search {
    float: right;
}
.owl-nav {
    display: none;
}


.rst-copyright .copyright {
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.rst-copyright .rst-social-menu {
    position: static!important;
    margin-top: 24px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi there, could you post your html please?

Comment: Is that not what's included? UTF-8

Comment: @DKyleo he posted a link to the website and if you inspect the website you can see all the HTML code

Comment: @Latoyah I had the exact same problem 2 weeks ago. The problem with my website was that I used the `row` class. So if you use that class, try to remove it. Otherwise figure out what the problem gives and replace that. Just start deleting classes that you didn't implement by yourself and test it

Comment: @Svenmarim Code in external sources is not allowed in SO. Please post all relevant codes IN THE QUESTION itself.

Comment: @Svenmarim Thanks, whats a row class and how do I find it?

Comment: @Latoyah it is a bootstrap class looked like this:  <div class="row"></div>

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your css file it should work for you

```
iframe {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.rst-copyright img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

[image]

you have used iframe inside iframe inside another iframe and its not a good idea

Comment: Thanks, have added this but it doesn't make any change?

Comment: Are you sure because I just check your site and it looks fine to me no horizontal scroll

Comment: Yep, on my mobile it cuts off the text on the left.

Comment: then you may need to remove your browser cache/cookies and try, have a good day

Comment: it is within posts that the text is an issue. Issue still present

Comment: Just noticed that it works fine within a chrome mobile preview, but just not on an actual phone?

Answer (score 0):

You just set max-width for all images commonly. And reduce the container width based on responsive. Try to add the overflow for body section as follow.

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.subscribe-box .block, .container {
    width: 300px;
}
}
```

[image: screen for your ref]

Comment: @Latoyah you have to add in your css file only. just update or replace the css I hope it will work for you.

Comment: @Sharvan Hi, this made no difference sadly.

Comment: @Rahul `overflow-x hidden` in this site we can use to avoid overflow div because its not a bootstrap based site to make it auto responsive column.

Comment: I know what this code does but here you are trying to hide content which is wrong, Im out now

Comment: @Latoyah I tried with my inspect mobile view. If you want clear answer you have to post your code with css with example link.

Comment: @Rahul. Okay noted.

Comment: @Sharvan How do I do that? It says there is a character limit on the posts so can't share the HTML

Comment: Yes. stack have some limit. try to use like codepen and jsfiddle

Comment: @Latoyah check my profile and email me for further clarification.